# How to remove tearing in videos with Nvidia driver?

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, video, 64-bit, tearing

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 as my HTPC OS on ION board. Tearing was always a big problem but this guide ([How To Fix Video Tearing In Videos; Nvidia, Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/01/how-to-fix-video-tearing-in-videos-nvidia-ubuntu/)) used to solve it in previous versions. I mean it used to because it doesn't solve it anymore.

I tried making same changes (although compiz config is little different and same options are in different panels) but with no success. I also tried to manually set resolution and refresh rate of HDTV in nvidia settings - no changes at all.

I know that open source drivers would solve a problem but it's not an option because I need VDPAU acceleration.

I've also read that completely disabling of Composite solves the problem - can't do that because compizconfig-settings-manager crashes on attempt.

More info about setup:

- Ubuntu 11.10 64bit
- Nvidia ION board
- newest official version of proprietary driver
- SMplayer with vdpau settings
- Full HD HDTV

Comment: I follow this question and can say even more - switching video outputs in player, 'unredirect fullscreen video' 'legacy fullscreen video' and so on didn't help. Killing compiz or running xfce helps. Switching to unity 2D doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Barafu Albino I found **temporary** solution to problem. In my case it's HTPC so I use it **only** for playing movies. Therefore I can use any desktop enviroment... including XFCE mentioned by Barafu.

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

This will install Xubuntu deksktop enviroment including XFCE.

Logout from ubuntu. Choose XFCE session

[image]

Enjoy tearless playback!

(make sure you've taken steps with vertical synchronisation and refresh rate settings as mentioned in [guide](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/01/how-to-fix-video-tearing-in-videos-nvidia-ubuntu/))